# Print Properties from Adobe Reader appear in Chinese

Tags: drivers, printing, language, adobe-reader

The title says it all...

Watch the video: http://youtu.be/TSZGG31C8j8

How can I change it to english?

[Here](http://reviews.cnet.com/inkjet-printers/hp-designjet-510/4505-3156_7-33503575.html) is what I am printing to.

Comment: you must of installed the wrong HP software for your printer, go back to the HP website and download the correct software for North America/English. If my comment below helps you, i'll make it into an answer form if you wish.

Comment: Quick Link -> http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3737531&ac.admitted=1391642848110.876444892.492883150